# Display command history on a linux HPC

Tags: linux, hpc

I logged in on a high performance computing cluster only to find that my root directory could not be reached:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /path/to/home: Stale file handle'
```

So I am curious as to what brought about this change. Is there any way I can find out a list of all commands executed in the last day or so on the HPC that can give me some clue as to what brought about the change?

I know this may be something only an admin support of the HPC can answer but im curious what I could do to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: if your system is shared, {history} wont help you. best practice would be using "tmux" on the cluster for your work.

Answer (score 1):

This command:

```
history
```

Should give you a list of commands that were entered from your account login. You would have to contact an admin to get any other answer.